# R: applying a function using values in a list

Tags: r

I am currently reading in a series of files, applying the same functions to them one at a time, and then merging the resulting data frames e.g.:

```
>MyRows <- c("RowA", "RowB", "RowC")
>
>File1_DF <- read.delim("\\\\DirectoryToFiles\\File1_Folder\\File1.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
>File1_DF <- as.data.frame(t(File1_DF[MyRows,]))
>File1_DF <- as.data.frame(t(File1_DF))
>mergeDF <- merge(mergeDF,File1_DF, by.x = "Row.names", by.y="row.names")
>
>File2_DF <- read.delim("\\\\DirectoryToFiles\\File2_Folder\\File2.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
>File2_DF <- as.data.frame(t(File2_DF[MyRows,]))
>File2_DF <- as.data.frame(t(File2_DF))
>mergeDF <- merge(mergeDF,File2_DF, by.x = "Row.names", by.y="row.names")
```

...etc

I want to know if I can use a list of the filenames c("File1", "File2", "File2") etc. and apply a function to do this in a more automated fasion?  This would involve using the list value in the directory path to read in the file i.e.

```
>*MyFilesValue*_DF <- read.delim("\\\\DirectoryToFolders\\*MyFilesValue*_Folder\\*MyFilesValue*.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Try `list.files` and `sapply` to flip through each filename.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `Reduce` and `Sys.glob`.

```
fpaths <- Sys.glob(file.path('\\\\DirectoryToFiles\\File1_Folder\\', 'File*.txt'))
dfs <- lapply(fpaths, read.delim, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)
dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(df) as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(t(df[MyRows,])))))
merge.fun <- function(mergeDF, nextDF) {
    merge(mergeDF, nextDF, by.x='Row.names', by.y='row.names')
}
result <- Reduce(merge.fun, c(mergeDF, dfs))
```

Comment: Why are you using `by.x='Row.names', by.y='row.names'`?